# How can I disable cookies when using basic auth on laravel?

Tags: laravel, cookies, basic-authentication

)

I'm having some very small IOT devices calling my API, which is made with Laravel. It uses Basic Auth, but can I avoid the laravel_session COOKIE and XSRF_TOKEN COOKIE to be set when using Basic Auth?

Every of these units call the API every 10 second. So if I can limit the traffic by disabling these COOKIES, that would be nice.

Thank you for your help!

Best Regards
Steffen

Comment: if you're using Laravel 9.x, that's a separate feature: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authentication#stateless-http-basic-authentication

Comment: If you are concerned about HTTP overhead, might be more efficient to use websockets instead.